# Code First database design issue - addresses

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a POCO that represents a form a user fills out. There are about 10 different addresses on the form, so I separated them out into a separate address POCO. The problem is how to set up the relationships.

What I would like to be able to do:

```
Public Class formtofillout
    Public Property form_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_1")> _
    Public Property address_1_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_2")> _
    Public Property address_2_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_3")> _
    Public Property address_3_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_4")> _
    Public Property address_4_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_5")> _
    Public Property address_5_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_6")> _
    Public Property address_6_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_7")> _
    Public Property address_7_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_8")> _
    Public Property address_8_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_9")> _
    Public Property address_9_id As Integer
    <ForeignKey("address_10")> _
    Public Property address_10_id As Integer

    Public Overridable Property address_1 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_2 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_3 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_4 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_5 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_6 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_7 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_8 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_9 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_10 As address

End Class
```

And not sure what to do on the address POCO to represent the other end of this relationship. BUT... this gives me a series of errors:

This one:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.formtofillout_dbo.address_1_id' on table 
'formtofillout' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION
or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

And I think a few others.

In order to get this to work, I did not create specific id columns in the 'formtofillout' POCO. Instead I just created the navigation properties:

```
Public Class formtofillout
    Public Property form_id As Integer

    Public Overridable Property address_1 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_2 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_3 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_4 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_5 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_6 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_7 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_8 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_9 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_10 As address

End Class
```

And then in the OnModelBuilding event, I added the following for each address:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasOptional(Function(n) n.address_1).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasOptional(Of address)(Function(n) n.address_1).WithMany().Map(Function(m) m.MapKey("address_1_id"))
```

This worked, and when I performed the migration, the table was created with the address_1_id, address_2_id columns, etc.... But these ID columns are in the database, but not in the POCO. How do I set this up to get the foreign key column in the POCO and the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add cascadeOnDelete(false) to the foreign key definition.
With multiple references back to one table or a->b->c->a type scenarios EF cant deal with that:
eg

```
   entity.HasRequired(p=>p.SomeNavProp)
              .WithMany()  
         //  .HasForeignKey(p=>p.RefId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Dont forget the Virtual Nav property definition. Didnt see that in your code extract

Comment: This did solve the cycles error, so marked as correct, but will post complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out. Here is my class:

```
Public Class formtofillout
    Public Property form_id As Integer

    Public Property address_1_id As Integer
    Public Property address_2_id As Integer
    Public Property address_3_id As Integer
    Public Property address_4_id As Integer
    Public Property address_5_id As Integer
    Public Property address_6_id As Integer
    Public Property address_7_id As Integer
    Public Property address_8_id As Integer
    Public Property address_9_id As Integer
    Public Property address_10_id As Integer

    Public Overridable Property address_1 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_2 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_3 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_4 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_5 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_6 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_7 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_8 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_9 As address
    Public Overridable Property address_10 As address

End Class
```

And here is the OnModelCreating in the DbContext, I did this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_1_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_2).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_2_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_3).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_3_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_4).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_4_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_5).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_5_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_6).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_6_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_7).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_7_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_8).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_8_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_9).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_9_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of formtofillout).HasRequired(Function(n) n.address_10).WithMany().HasForeignKey(Function(a) a.address_10_id).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```